# Conditions for defining new metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(M,d)$ is metric. I have proven that if $\psi\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is non-decreasing, subadditive and satisfies $\psi(x)=0\iff x=0$ for $x\ge0$, then $$\rho(x,y)=\psi(d(x,y))$$ is a metric on $M$.

But I want to `tweak' the restriction of this statement, I want to use differentiability of $\psi$. I found the following:

> Suppose $(M,d)$ is metric and $\psi\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is
>   differentiable with continuous non-increasing derivative $\psi'$ and
>   $\psi(0)=0$. Then $\psi$ is non-decreasing and subadditive.

I have also proven this statement, but is $\rho=\psi(d(x,y))$ a metric in this situation? And if not, what is a sufficient condition on the derivative $\psi'$ to turn $\rho$ into a metric on $M$?

Comment: If $\psi$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, and the derivative is everywhere positive, then $\psi$ is strictly increasing. If in addition $\psi(0) = 0$, then you're in the earlier situation and $\psi\circ d$ is again a metric.

Comment: @WNY:  Something's not quite right.  If $\psi(x) = x^2$, for example, the $\psi\circ d$ isn't a metric for the usual $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$.  Consider the three points $0$, $1$ and $2$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $\psi(d(0,2)) = 4$, while $\psi(d(0,1)) + \psi(d(1,2)) = 1+1 < 4$, so the triangle inequality fails.  You really need to know something about $\psi$s derivative, that the derivative is non-increasing.

Comment: See also: 
[How do you prove triangle inequality for this metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862037) and [Is there a continuous, strictly increasing function $f: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ with $f(0) = 0$ such that $\tilde d = f\circ d$ is not a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/715293)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly exclude $\psi'(0)=0$ (and thus due to the range of $\psi$ it follows $\psi'(0)\gt 0$) or alternatively require $\psi'$ strictly decreasing in any interval $(0,\epsilon)$. Otherwise, $\psi$ might satisfy the starting conditions of your second statement, but can violate $\psi(x)=0\iff x=0$, because if $\psi'$ can be zero on a positive interval starting at $0$, $\psi$ would be constant on that interval.

Then, from the starting conditions, $\psi' > 0$ on an interval near $0$ and thus $\psi$ strictly increasing, so $\neq 0$ on that interval. Now, from the given range of $\psi$ and $\psi'$ non-increasing it follows that $\psi' \ge 0$ everywhere - if it was not, then you can derive that $\psi$ must eventually become negative, which is a contradiction.

That in turn implies $\psi$ is strictly increasing near $0$ and (not necessarily strictly) increasing everywhere, and thus the remaining needed precondition of the first statement $\psi(x)=0\iff x=0$ follows.

Comment: Function $f(x) = x^{-1}$ with domain $(0,\infty)$ has range $(0,\infty)$, but $f'(x) < 0$.

Comment: But it does not have $f(0)=0$ as required here.

Comment: I just meant that "from the given range of $\psi$ it follows that $\psi' \geq 0$ everywhere" is not clear, you need to stress that $\psi'$ is non-increasing (without this it doesn't work).

Comment: Fair enough, edited that in.