# Distance Functions

Tags: metric-spaces

I am still unsure as to how to go about proving if something is a metric space or if a specified distance function defines a metric space.  I am attempting to tackle the following and would like any tips\corrections if possible. I know that a distance function must satisfy the following:

1. $d(x,y)\geq 0$ (equals $0$ if $x=y$)
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

> Suppose $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a distance function. Are the following also distance function $\rho: X \times X \to R$:

1. $\rho(x,y)= (d(x,y))^2$
2. $\rho(x,y)= (d(x,y))^{1/2}$
3. $\rho(x,y)= 3d(x,y)$
4. $\rho(x,y)= (d(x,y))^{1/2} + 2d(x,y)$

Proof:

1. Clearly the first two properties hold. The triangle inequality comes down to showing if $d(x,z)^2 \leq d(x,y)^2 + d(y,z)^2$. We run into a contradiction if we let $X$ be the real line and consider the points $x=1, z=-1, y=0$.
2. Not quite sure
3. Clearly, the first two properties hold.  When we face the triangle inequality, we can factor out the $3$ and our inequality is our usual triangle inequality which we assume holds since we assume $d$ is a distance function.
4. Because of $2$ I am unsure about it.  I believe it will\will not hold depending on this problem.

Comment: This might be of interest in connection with problems like this: 
[Conditions for defining new metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123454),
[How do you prove triangle inequality for this metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862037) and [Is there a continuous, strictly increasing function $f: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ with $f(0) = 0$ such that $\tilde d = f\circ d$ is not a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/715293)

Answer (score 0):

For 1., let $X$ be the real line with the usual metric, and take $x=-1$, $z=1$, and $y=0$.

For 2.,
$$\rho(x,z) \le \sqrt{d(x,y)+d(y,z)} \le \sqrt{d(x,y)} + \sqrt{d(y,z)} = \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z).$$